# Lucene.Net MoreLikeThis returns 0 interesting terms and no clauses in the query

Tags: asp.net, search, lucene.net, morelikethis

I'm trying to implement the Lucene.Net MoreLikeThis query but it doesn't seem to be able to find anything interesting in the document to search the index.

In my scenario, the user has clicked "More Like This" link on the search results webpage, this passes the document id on the query string. My Lucene.Net code looks like this:

```
var similarSearch = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
similarSearch.SetFieldNames(new[] { "Place", "Subject", "Description", "Name", "Town", "Occupation" });
similarSearch.MinWordLen = 3;
similarSearch.Boost = true;

var terms = similarSearch.RetrieveInterestingTerms(docid);
var doc = reader[docid];

var searchQuery = similarSearch.Like(docid);
```

Following execution; the terms variable is an empty array, the doc variable contains the document and the searchQuery has no clauses. When I run the search using the query it returns no documents.

My conclusion is I am able to get the document from the reader, but the MoreLikeThis object is unable to find anything to build a query from.

Any idea why?

Comment: You are suppose to search using the `searchQuery`, like: `Hits hits = searcher.Search(searchQuery);`. Take a look at [this sample](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/contrib-queries/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html)

Comment: @rae1n That is the next line in the code `var hits = searcher.Search(searchQuery, 15000);`. Following execution `hits.TotalHits` is 0. I ommitted it from the sample as I assume the cause is that lack of clauses in the `searchQuery`

Comment: Got it. In that case chances are there isn't anything like that document, at least not enough to make the cut...

Comment: @rae1n the documents are small, but in at least two of the fields there are many more documents that are the same. I think the fact the query has zero clauses and it's unable to retrieve any interesting terms points to a different problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may need to set one or more of the following parameters on the MoreLikeThis object: Analyzer, MinTermFreq, and/or MinDocFreq

I had the same issue - no results being returned.  Once I set the above parameters (try setting both of the minimums to 1), it worked.

Comment: Thank you Phil. Unfortunately the requirement got dropped in the end. Hopefully this will help someone else though

Comment: I was literally tearing my hair out with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It saved my time.